# WPF define resource for root element's attribute in a view

Tags: wpf, resources

I have a view:

```
<ad:DockingManager x:Class="Proj.UI.View.DockingManagerView"
                           ... a lot of xmlns ...
                           ActiveContent="{Binding Path=ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ActiveDocumentConverter}}">
    <ad:DockingManager.Resources>
        <ad:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ActiveDocumentConverter"/>
    </ad:DockingManager.Resources>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

This will not work.

Where should I move the resource to be available in the root element's attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the converter(s) to the App.xaml - resource, so that you can have central repository of resource.

Take a look at the below link for some other aspect of sharing converters.

[Should I declare converters in App.xaml or as a per-file resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659285/should-i-declare-converters-in-app-xaml-or-as-a-per-file-resource)

Comment: The link you provided described a pretty good way of handling converters. Thank you.