# MarkUpExtension in .Net Metro App

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml

I am using C#, XAML in Microsoft Visual Studio.

In WPF with the desktop version of the .Net framework, there is a markupextension class under namespace System.Windows.Markup. Saw it from the accepted answer in this post [Should I declare converters in App.xaml or as a per-file resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659285/should-i-declare-converters-in-app-xaml-or-as-a-per-file-resource)

Is there an equivalent or something that is close to it in for the mobile version of .Net you use to create Metro apps? I can't seem to find the appropriate namespace or is it not supported?

Comment: if you want checkboxes that are mutually exclusive, then don't use checkboxes. that's not what they're for. use radio buttons instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "in Visual Studio". VS is only IDE, has nothing to do with .NET library. Maybe you are using wrong project type or wrong target framework. Or you are missing some references in your project.

Comment: @MarcB,@jure Sorry, that was the wrong title. I saw a similar post that was for wpf using markupextension and ivalueconverter, I was just wondering if there is something equivalent in Visual Studio ( for Windows metro app).

Comment: @learner ..ah you are talking about WinRT applications. Im afraid there is no support for creating custom markup extensions on that platform. But i may be wrong.

Comment: @jure I checked it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx and it wasn't supported for the metro apps but I was just wondering if there is something equivalent or close to it that I didn't know. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WinRT (Aka Metro) [does not have MarkupExtension class](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/16166940-94ef-47bc-a083-2e8303f76d1f).

Comment: Is it worth the trouble to create a custom one?

Comment: @learner I don't think you will be able to do that, at least not in a way that can then be used from XAML the same way you do it in WPF. Microsoft is screwing all this stuff up so much that we will all end up doing Objective-C in a Mac and forget MS forever.

Comment: For any UWP developer stumbling upon this in the future, there's now some support for it, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156782/how-does-one-use-the-uwp-markupextension-class