# Is it possible to implement your own markup extension in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to implement my own markup extension, it would be something that could be used to pass two values to a property like:

```
{Foo Value1={x:Null} Value2={x:Null}}
```

I've looked into some websites and there is always someone saying something about extending the MarkupExtension class. I've tried to do the same within a Windows Phone 8.1 project and this class doesn't seen to be available. Can someone point me to the right direction? What should I do to implement something like that? There is a better alternative to extending the MarkupExtension class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MarkUpExtension in .Net Metro App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927572/markupextension-in-net-metro-app)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to do that. Why do you need it? If you tell us about the markup extension that you want to write, we might be able to give you an alternative approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible, no. Very sorry to be the bearer of bad news.